# MYSQL where $var AND IS NULL

Tags: php, mysql, select, isnull

I have problem handling information from my MySQL Database, I have this code :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM obojok WHERE id_uzivatela = '".$_SESSION['uzivatel']['id']."' AND id_zvierata IS NULL";
      $res = $conn->query($sql);
      if ($res === TRUE) {
        echo "DATA Obtained";
      } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
      }
```

But the only thing I get is this error :

> Error: SELECT * FROM obojok WHERE id_uzivatela = '******' AND id_zvierata IS NULL
>   
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'is null AND id_uzivatela='20170'' at line 1

Comment: The error does not match your query

Comment: How do you mean ?

Comment: he means that `is null AND id_uzivatela='20170'` (from the error msg) is nowhere to be found in your actual query. you might want to check again if the code that you show here is correctly copypasted

Comment: error message and your sql does not match

Comment: `mysqli` or `PDO`? Tag the question with the MySQL library you use.

Comment: if ($res === TRUE) { 
i have triple === -.-
thank you :)

Comment: echo "Error123: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error; ... change this line then run again .. can you confirm Error123: is showing ?

Comment: @MinarMnr it will be showing, but$conn->error is the last error, it does not mean it is the error from last query.

Answer (score 1):

Your query has no problem... The error you see is from another query.

From documentation, the return of $conn->query should not be strictly equal to TRUE

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object.

If you want to see if your query worked, do not test on the true value, you are better testing on not false...

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM obojok WHERE id_uzivatela = '".$_SESSION['uzivatel']['id']."' AND id_zvierata IS NULL";
  $res = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($res != FALSE) {
    echo "DATA Obtained";
  } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }
```

EDIT:
I have completely forgot to note that since the error you see is coming from another query, you have to repair that query too! One habit I had for a long time when writing queries like that is to write it this way:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM obojok WHERE id_uzivatela = '".$_SESSION['uzivatel']['id']."' AND id_zvierata IS NULL";
$res = $conn->query($sql) or throw new Exception("Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error);
```

What this means is make $res = to the $conn->query value if it is not equal to false. If it is false, throw an exception with the relevant information.

If you do that, you won't have to test after if $res is good or not. It will also greatly help you find where errors are happening.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in the query. At least, not in the query posted in the question.

The error is in the PHP code.

A `SELECT` query never returns `TRUE`. It returns an object when it succeeds. Either a [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) or a [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php), depending on what MySQL library you use.

Your query succeeds and `$res` is an object. It is not `TRUE`, the test `$res === TRUE`  fails and the code erroneously runs the `else` branch. It then reports the correct query it just ran successfully and the error message of the most recent failed query. This explains why the fragment of query listed by the server in the error message does not match the query you ran.

The correct way to check the result of your query is `$res != FALSE`. It doesn't matter if you use `==` or `===`, `$res` is either an object (not equal with `FALSE` no matter how it is compared) or `FALSE`. You can, as well, just use `$res`. It is the same thing:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM obojok WHERE id_uzivatela = '".$_SESSION['uzivatel']['id']."' AND id_zvierata IS NULL";
$res = $conn->query($sql);
if ($res) {
    echo "DATA Obtained";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Depending on the MySQL library you use, read more about [`mysqli::query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) and/or [`PDO::query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php).

Answer (score -2):

SELECT * FROM obojok WHERE id_uzivatela = '".$_SESSION['uzivatel']['id']."' OR id_zvierata IS NULL

Comment: this is not a solution @Adrian Wolff

Comment: Why did you change the behaviour of the query?? It was fine as it was.